# Employer's duty of care to employee having a stroke

Tags: health

My husband was sent home in a taxi after suffering a stroke at work,have had no communication with his work what so ever do they have a duty of care to make sure that he got the proper treatment : put into an ambulance instead of a taxi ?

Comment: Is your husband OK? Is he getting the correct treatment now? Sometimes a stroke is difficult to spot - we should all learn FAST - http://www.chss.org.uk/FAST/

Comment: I would also say that everybody should learn basic first aid

Comment: I don't know about your country, but here it is actually faster to take taxi, than pray that ambulance, for once, arrives on time

Comment: Another factor:  Even if there isn't a duty to provide care there might be a duty not to provide wrong care--and sending a stroke patient somewhere other than a hospital is wrong care.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, healthcare isn't the employer's responsibility, but they do own some responsibility for the handling of a medical incident that occurred in the workplace.

Answer (score 6):

Your first priority is to ensure your husband gets the proper treatment.

Once your husband is able to do so safely, have him explain what happened and make sure it is written down and clear. After that, he will need to consult his trade union representative, or, if he is not a union member, an employment solicitor. They will be able to advise further or make a referral on to a specialist.

In many jurisdictions, employers owe their employees a duty of care which would certainly involve calling an ambulance in emergencies. Exactly when and what other precautions they might be expected to take will vary hugely: an employer might not, for instance, be liable if they had made reasonable attempts to determine what was wrong and no indication that it was a stroke (some are very brief); on the other hand, in some places, if they didn't ensure their staff were adequately trained in first aid, they might have a liability. We are not lawyers and cannot advise you on the legal situation in your circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You need to seek legal advice.

A hospital will not allow go home in taxi.

If they suspected a medical emergency then yes they should have sent him to the hospital in an ambulance.  Your husband could have requested medical care.  Did your husband get in the taxi on his own free will?  Did work deny medical care?

Was your husband was conscious and coherent when they put him in the taxi?  Even at a hospital I can deny medical care.  I am not an attorney but unless they put him in the taxi without his knowledge or consent they are not liable.  A stoke often represents as as just discomfort that even medical professional might not recognize. If he went down and had slurred speech and one side of his face limp the OK they should have demanded a ambulance.  But a stroke 
can often be just I don't feel good.